# Drawing line between beginning and end points with lat/long data in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a table 500 entries that each have a beginning latitude, beginning longitude, ending latitude and ending longitude.

I would like to draw a line between the beginning lat/long and the ending lat/long of each entry (row).

What is the simplest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Try XY to Line tool?

Comment: Could you specify your Arcgis version number and licence level ?

Comment: The XY to Line worked perfectly!  Thank you so much!

Comment: @gisnside If you write this up as an official answer I will accept it

Comment: All credit rather goes to @mkennedy :)

Comment: @gisnside Ah yes! you're right.

Comment: @mkennedy If you write this up as an official answer I will accept it